# Error from android studio: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android

I've started a new project with Android Studio and I get the following message:

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap. Please assign more memory to Gradle in the
>   project's gradle.properties file. For example, the following line, in
>   the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024
>   MB: *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m* Read
>   Gradle's configuration guide
> Read
>   about Java's heap size

Comment: Have you tried to increase the heap, like described in the error description?

Comment: *How can I solve this?* the solution is literally given in the error message

Answer (score 0):

Trying what's suggested in the message sounds like a good start.
You can also set an env `export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need screenshot.It just in you root view  .If there is not file,create one.

[image]